# Track exact Geolocation with Google Analytics and show on Map

Tags: geolocation, google-analytics, server-side, latitude-longitude

**Situation:** I want to track some Data with Google Analytics on the server-side.

**Problem:** My application is able to provide an exact geolocation (lat, lng). I want to track it with GA as the 'users location' so i can show them on a Map in the GA Dashboard.

I know i may track custom variables/events, but am unsure how to plot them on a map in Google Analytics. My company would like to stay with one reporting tool.

Comment: ...This is problematic, as Google Analytics's Terms of Service prohibits the transmission of personally identifiable information. You should look into using a different tool.

Comment: Google already has an "approximation" (city/latitude/longitude) of the visitors.  Is the Map Overlay not accurate enough?  You say you have "exact" location.  So I presume you have actual GPS coordinates and not "approximations" based on the internet ISP as I suspect Google Analytics is using.

Comment: yes my application handles GPS coordinates from clients and i wanted to track them

Comment: Are there any other tools that provide this type of functionality now?  It's been 9 months since this post was made, hoping there might be an update....

Comment: Lat/Long coordinates are not personally identifiable information. Even if it was, iPhone users must explicitly consent to sharing their location before any request is made to my API. I'd love to hear about a product that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to plot these in the Google Analytics dashboard, but you should not let this stop you from moving forward. You could do this fairly easily by saving the geolocations in a custom variable and then pulling that data and then plotting it using a combination of the Data Export API and the Google Maps API. You will not, however, be able to embed this within the Google Analytics dashboard.

Comment: Down voted; while technically feasible to store any type of data in GA; PI and fine grained geolocation data is banned from google's terms of service; https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en#geolocation  You could store some sort of obfuscated foreign key in GA and then reconcile it (outside of GA) in your own private dashboard by merging the foreign key from GA with your own fine grained location data

Answer (score 1):

It currently is not possible to provide geolocation information directly to google analytics.  Google automatically extrapolates that information based on data gathered from the web client (e.g. ip address), and you cannot provide that information since you are invoking tracking on the server-side.

It would be nice if google added the ability to provide at least city level geolocation data for server-side tracking, but it doesn't appear possible at this point in time.